# Installing OpenWrap

Tags: .net, openwrap

I'm trying to install OpenWrap form the [website](http://www.openwrap.org/). Unfortunetly when running o.exe app crashes and "openwrap shell has stopped working". Does anyone have similar problem?
Here is callstack:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was clos
ed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unabl
e to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibl
y closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existin
g connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenWrap.Preloading.NotifyProgressWebClient.DownloadDataCompleted(Object s
ender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
ontextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_Thre
adPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is down and as we have a dead community I can't be arsed to restart it. That's why you'd have problems.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me (maybe you have some tutorial) how to install wrap without using site?